# growing struct array in function

Tags: c, struct

I have a file which is includes multiple commands. When i see the right command, I must add dynamically created struct in struct array.

I created struct but i cant add it to array in `main()` function.

**Here is what i did:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct book{
    char name[30];
    int page_number;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file.");
    }

    read_line(fp);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

void read_line(FILE *fp){
    char str[100];
    while(1){
        if(fgets(str, 100, fp) != NULL){
            printf("%s", str);
            split_line(str);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void split_line(char *line){
    char ** res  = NULL;
    char *  p    = strtok (line, " ");
    int n_spaces = 0, i;

/* split string and append tokens to 'res' */

    while (p) {
        res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);
        if (res == NULL){
            printf("Memory allocation failed!");
        } else {
            res[n_spaces-1] = p;
            p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }
    }

/* realloc one extra element for the last NULL */

    res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * (n_spaces+1));
    res[n_spaces] = 0;

    command_check(res);
    free(res);
}

void command_check(char **tokens){
    if(strcmp(tokens[0], "CREATEBOOK") == 0){
        create_book(tokens);
    } else if (strcmp(tokens[0], "REMOVEBOOK") == 0){
        remove_book(tokens);
    }
}

void create_book(char **tokens){
    book created_book;
    strcpy(created_book.name, tokens[1]);
    created_book.page_number = atoi(tokens[2]);
    //then what im stuck here
}
```

Comment: Your `main()` function contains no array, or pointer to array, of your book structures.  You're probably going to need one.  You'll need to pass it to the data reading function — I'm not sure that `read_line()` is a good name for a function that's intended to read a whole file.  You should avoid infinite loops; you should use `while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp) != NULL)` for the loop, which means you don't need the `if` or `break` inside the loop.

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. Moreover, in your program you have used some nested function definition. Is it all of your code?

Comment: @Aznaveh yes this is all of my code. I just didnt write `delete_book()` function. I need a struct book array and grow it dynamically.

Comment: There is so much chain function. Because of that I can't use return type `create_book()` function and that make things hard.

Comment: I tried to rewrite the program and disentangle your functions; using realloc seem the right work. However, I don't get your problem yet

Comment: For example when we read _CREATEBOOK "Alice" 324_ from txt file, we should add it to struct array and then we can access it's properties `book[0].name` and `book[0].page_number`. I am asking how do i do that dynamically.